# How to enable dex compiler D8(Next-generation Dex Compiler) in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, dex

With the release of [Android Studio 3.0 Beta release](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-2.html), the android studio provides next-generation dex compiler, D8 to compile code and build android APK. Currently, D8 is available for preview.

Check more details:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html

**How to enable build using D8 in android studio?**

Comment: This is also referenced in this video : https://youtu.be/LhaSi6_i2bo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To enable D8 for your *Android Studio 3.0 Beta*, you can add following line in your project's **gradle.properties** file:

```
android.enableD8=true
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do not have a **gradle.properties** file simple create it in your's root project directory (or folder) and add this line:

> android.enableD8=true

Answer (score 1):

R8, is available for preview as part of **Android Studio 3.0 Beta**

To try it, set the following in your project's `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableR8=true
```

R8 also has full mode that is not directly compatible with Proguard. In order to try that out you can additionally set the following in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=true
```

You can check this [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html) for further details

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can enable D8 via `android.enableD8=true` in your **gradle.properties** but in case you encountered compile error as such **"Process 'command 'xxx/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"** on a project migrated/imported into the new Android Studios 3.1+ , then try with this:

`android.enableD8.desugaring=true`

This will execute **desugaring** as part of **D8** which speeds up the process.